# SignalR package for Angular 14 and .Net framework 4.7

Tags: .net, angular, signalr, angular14

I am working on angular 14 and backend is on .Net framework 4.7. I am trying to communicate with server using signalR. Angular package @microsoft/signalR is giving below error when trying to communicate

```
Failed to start the connection: Error: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server.
```

Please help me which package should we use to connect with server signalR

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr